# Is there a textarea/rich text editor that allows the user to follow links that render in them while entering?

Tags: javascript, html, fckeditor, richtext

I am looking for something like like FCKEditor that allows users to follow links by left clicking them.

For example, the markdown editor in StackOverflow does not allow you to click the links you add as you are entering data into the editor.  I would like to render a text area pre-populated with some links to lab results that the user can choose to review while making their comments.

Answer (score 1):

both tinyMCE and fck editor will highlight the links with blue color and if you ctrl+click on them, will open in a new tab/window (depends of you browser configuration)

Comment: Does not work in IE for me, but works fine in FF. I did not know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most HTML richtext don't do anything to the link (with the exception that you can place the cursor in them with a single left click, in order to edit their text) that would prevent you from, for instance, right-clicking to open the link, copy it, or whatever your browser allows.

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) allows you to preview within the same page and then click on any links with the click of a button/icon. I'm thinking there must be a way of triggering this outside of the TinyMCE and possibly having it populate another field/area. (You probably could also grab the value of the textarea and put that somewhere else on the page.)

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Kind of, put the preview approach is less than ideal.  The closest user experience I can think of is when users perform a 'CTRL-click' in Microsoft word to follow links while editing a word document.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try a preview mode, just like StackOverflow. See [How can I enable live preview for FCKeditor in an ASP.Net site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293854/how-can-i-enable-live-preview-for-fckeditor-in-an-asp-net-site)