# How can I enable live preview for FCKeditor in an ASP.Net site?

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg, fckeditor, live-preview

Over in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84353/i-need-a-wysiwyg-web-editor-web-based) question, Scott writes that it is possible to get the current HTML for what's written in the FCKeditor by using `FCKeditorAPI.__Instances['instanceNameHere'].GetHTML();`

Could someone provide step-by-step instructions on how to accomplish this in an ASP.NET page? All I currently have so far in the .aspx file is this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2" %>
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ... %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Create a new piece</h2>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ID="FCKeditor1" runat="server">
</FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor>

<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" />
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript

Well you can do this here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(’IDFromFCKEditor’);
    oEditor.Events.AttachEvent( 'OnSelectionChange', function() {
        document.getElementById("PreviewDiv").innerHTML = oEditor.GetHTML(true);
    }) ;
</script>
```

Source http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API

Comment: In case anyone needs this later, you will want to wrap the code José provides inside the following:

function FCKeditor_OnComplete(editorInstance)